# what is the last parameter in getInt() method in SharedPerference Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

What is meant by "-1" in last line of this SharedPreference program ?

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourIntValue);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

Comment: It's default first value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a default value which will be return if `your_int_key` is not found in the preference data.

Answer (score 0):

```
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

Here last parameter '-1'is default value.
If nothing (int) is saved in sharedPreferrence for key 'your_int_key' then it will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

U need to pass a default value in second parameter. In case the value you are looking for returns null.